# Canvas 2d grid display won't display

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have the following code which is doesn't throw any errors in the console. I'm trying to display a 2D array as a grid. Images are defined with the correct path. However, currently only the outline of the canvas will appear.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    canvas { border: 2px solid black;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
</body>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var arrayN = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0]
];


var grey = new Image(32,32);
var forrest = new Image(32,32);

grey.src = '1.PNG';
forrest.src = '2.PNG';

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++){
for (let j = 0; j < arrayN[i].length; j++){
  if (arrayN[i][j] === 0){
    ctx.drawImage(grey, posX, posY, 32,32);
  }
  if (arrayN[i][j] !== 0){
    ctx.drawImage(forrest, posX, posY, 32,32);
  }
  posX +=32;
}
posX = 0;
posY +=32;
}

</script>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/orangegoat/swLabv43/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling the main reason is the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. That is, we tend to think that each line runs after the previous, that's only half the story. Each line will *begin* in order, but it won't wait for the previous line to finish. Because of this, I believe your for-loops are trying to draw the images before they've finished loading. I tried putting them in a `setTimeout()` function, and it works.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // your for-loops here
}, 1000);    // 1000 ms = 1 second of delay
```

Of course, this assumes that the images load within 1 second, which won't always be the case. So instead, I recommend using `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arrayN[i].length; j++) {
            if (arrayN[i][j] === 0) {
                ctx.drawImage(grey, posX, posY, 32, 32);
            }
            if (arrayN[i][j] !== 0) {
                ctx.drawImage(forrest, posX, posY, 32, 32);
            }
            posX += 32;
        }
        posX = 0;
        posY += 32;
    }
};
```

That should be enough to fix it. But personally, I would've done

```
window.onload = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arrayN[i].length; j++) {
            ctx.drawImage(arrayN[i][j] === 0 ? grey : forrest, 32 * j, 32 * i, 32, 32);
        }
    }
};
```

It's a lot more concise. A few explanations:

- `window.onload = () => {` is the same as `window.onload = function() {`. It's just using the new ES6 syntax, which I presume you have at least some knowledge of, since you're using the `let` keyword. And on that note, you might want to consider replacing *all* your `var` keywords with `let` or `const`.
- It's redundant to use `posX` and `posY`, because they're only getting increased by 32 each time, and `i` and `j` are getting incremented automatically by the for-loop, so you might as well just use `i * 32` and `j * 32`. Then you can delete the variables `posX` and `posY` entirely.
- I'd advise against using two if-statements that test for opposite conditions. It's better to use an if-else statement. It's even better to use the ternary operator (`? :`) when the differences in what you want to change are small. In this case, you're only changing the first parameter in `drawImage`, so I thought this was a suitable situation.

Hope that all helped!